# Pass a class as a parameter of a TypeScript property decorator

Tags: typescript, decorator

Is it and how is it possible to pass a TypeScript Class as a parameter of a **property** Decorator? I'd like to do the following

```
class Bar {
}

class Foo {
  @MyDecorator(Bar)
  toto;
}

function MyDecorator(clazz) {
  // clazz is undefined here
  // i'd like to do: const x = new clazz()
}
```

If I use a class decorator, it works though, any thought?

Comment: Your code seems to be working in playground

Comment: Oh right, interesting... In my real situation I am importing the class so maybe that's the problem